# Regex to get specific data from xml

Tags: regex, xml

The text I have is:

```html
<aa><bb>hello1</bb><id>123</id><cc>hello2</cc></aa>
<aa><bb>hello3</bb><id>456</id><cc>hello4</cc></aa>
bla bla bla
<aa><bb>hello5</bb><id>789</id><cc>hello6</cc></aa>
<aa><bb>hello7</bb><id>987</id><cc>hello8</cc></aa>
```

Now, if the needed id is 789, I need the regex to give me

```html
<aa><bb>hello5</bb><id>789</id><cc>hello6</cc></aa>
```

Must understand that there can be more aa elements, and so more bla bla between them, but
I need the specific aa that has the specific id.

I tried a lot of regexes, but any of them is working for me.

Comment: Why are you trying to mess around with this using regex to begin with, why are you not using a proper XML parser?

Comment: I am using Powershell. So the regex should be used in it.